# Moving Receiver to thread complains about Sync, but expected Send

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to reference, via an `Arc`, a receiver into a thread, so I can do centralized pub-sub via dispatcher. However, I get the following error:

```
src/dispatcher.rs:58:11: 58:24 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `core::cell::UnsafeCell<std::sync::mpsc::Flavor<dispatcher::DispatchMessage>>` [E0277]
src/dispatcher.rs:58           thread::spawn(move || {
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/dispatcher.rs:58:11: 58:24 note: `core::cell::UnsafeCell<std::sync::mpsc::Flavor<dispatcher::DispatchMessage>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
src/dispatcher.rs:58           thread::spawn(move || {
```

Wat! I thought only `Send` was required for moving across channels? The code of `DispatchMessage` is:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
enum DispatchType {
    ChangeCurrentChannel,
    OutgoingMessage,
    IncomingMessage
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct DispatchMessage {
   dispatch_type: DispatchType,
   payload: String
}
```

Both `String` and surely `Enum` are `Send`, right? Why is it complaining about `Sync`?

The relevant part from the dispatcher:

```
pub fn start(&self) {
   let shared_subscribers = Arc::new(self.subscribers);
   for ref broadcaster in &self.broadcasters {
      let shared_broadcaster = Arc::new(Mutex::new(broadcaster));

      let broadcaster = shared_broadcaster.clone();
      let subscribers = shared_subscribers.clone();
      thread::spawn(move || {
         loop {
            let message = &broadcaster.lock().unwrap().recv().ok().expect("Couldn't receive message in broadcaster");
            match subscribers.get(type_to_str(&message.dispatch_type)) {
              Some(ref subs) => { 
                  for sub in subs.iter() { sub.send(*message).unwrap(); }
              },
              None => ()
            }

         }
      });
   }
}
```

Full dispatcher code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/timonv/5cdc56bf671cee69d3fa

If it's still relevant, built against the 5-2-2015 nightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Jorge is correct in the general sense, the problem with this particular code is that creating an Arc Mutex takes ownership of the argument and can thus not be a reference. This makes sense when you think about it. How can you lock something that is not yours? Or more concrete, we need to lock whatever is at that memory location, not the pointer to it.

Changing the code to create the Arc Mutex when the broadcaster is added to the struct solves the problem. This would change that part of the code to:

```
pub fn register_broadcaster(&mut self, broadcaster: &mut Broadcast) {
   let handle = Arc::new(Mutex::new(broadcaster.broadcast_handle()));
   self.broadcasters.push(handle);
}
```

And then the start method of the dispatcher would look like:

```
pub fn start(&self) {
   // Assuming that broadcasters.clone() copies the vector, but increase ref count on els
   for broadcaster in self.broadcasters.clone() {
      let subscribers = self.subscribers.clone();
      thread::spawn(move || {
         loop {
            let message = broadcaster.lock().unwrap().recv().ok().expect("Couldn't receive message in broadcaster or channel hung up");
            match subscribers.get(type_to_str(&message.dispatch_type)) {
              Some(ref subs) => { 
                  for sub in subs.iter() { sub.send(message.clone()).unwrap(); }
              },
              None => ()
            }

         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`Arc` requires `Sync`, and it seems to me like you're attempting to put channels inside an `Arc`. Channels are not `Sync`, neither `Sender` nor `Receiver`.

Without knowing what you're trying to do, here are some things that may help you:

- it's possible to clone `Sender`, so where you would probably `Arc` a `T` and share it between many threads, you can instead clone a `Sender` and send it to many threads, since it *is* `Send`
- otherwise (and especially for `Receiver`, which you can't clone) you have to stick it inside an `Arc<Mutex<T>>`, which makes it `Sync`.

Comment: Oh woops, old code, let me wrap it back in a mutex.

Comment: I'm trying to build a dispatcher, so a broadcaster can register their endpoint (a Receiver) and a subscriber can subscribe to events (via a Sender).

Then, for every receiver a thread gets boot up, listening on that receiver, and then sends over messages to the senders that are listening to that particular message

Comment: So, what's the question now? My answer didn't address the Sync issue?

Comment: Why the error? Your Arc/Mutex answer is the right answer for a channel with primitive types. However, that's not the case and I'm pretty sure this has to do with the struct.

Comment: I think I understand your question now. Your `self.subscribers` is `broadcasters: Vec<mpsc::Receiver<DispatchMessage>>`. You stick that in an `Arc`, and like I said, channel endpoints _themselves_ are _not sync_. It's not a situation like everywhere else, where `W` in `W<T>` would be `Sync` if `T` is `Sync`; channel endpoints are _fundamentally_ not `Sync` as currently implemented in the std, since they contain `UnsafeCell`s.

Comment: Your `DispatchMessage` struct is `Sync` AFAIK, since the types it consists of are `Sync`, so that's not the issue, as I expressed with the `W<T>` example above.

Comment: See also the gist for the full code. But like you said, an Arc<Mutex<Receiver>> should be sync? Then why is there still this error about the unsafecell on DispatchMessage requiring sync?

Comment: Indeed that should be `Sync`. However, I'm referring to line 50: `let shared_subscribers = Arc::new(self.subscribers);` and I know that `self.subscribers` is of type `subscribers: HashMap<&'static str, Vec<mpsc::Sender<DispatchMessage>>>,`. You protected the broadcasters behind a mutex, but not the subscribers.

Comment: Same error with the subscribers removed and no extra error (although you're never sure I guess). I can always clone that over if I really need to (start only runs once), but its not the issue.

Comment: Can you please update the code and show the latest error, even if it's the same? I checked here on SO and on the gist.

Comment: This is the latest code. You want me to simplify the example so subscribers are left out?